# Palindrome numbers get out 6 numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, palindrome

I need to write code which would get out 6 palindrome numbers on screen.

**Example:**

```
300003
310013
320023
330033
340043
350053
```

**Findings:**
So far, I have just written code how to check if it's a palindrome number or not:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, num, dig, rev = 0;
   
    cout << "Insert number": << endl;
    cin >> num;          
    n = num;

    while (num != 0);
    {
        dig = num % 10;
        rev = (rev * 10) + dig;
        num = num / 10;
    } 

    if (n == rev)
        cout << "This is palindrome "<< rev << endl;
    else
        cout << "This is not palindrome "<< rev << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `std::cout << "300003 310013 320023 330033 340043 350053";`?

Comment: Can you please define any 6 ..

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) cout << (300003 + (10 * i) + (10000 * i));`.....

Comment: Example if i Insert number : 300003 then code should print 310013 , 320023 etc.

Comment: You mean to get next pallindrome number https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115593/proper-implementation-to-find-next-palindrome-from-spoj

Comment: Yes exactly that is what i ment and trying to solve

Answer (score 3):

You are stuck in an infinite while loop int the line:

```
while (num != 0);
```

So remove the semicolon and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is convert the number that was given into a string via std::to_string.

Then use std::reverse to reverse the string, and compare to the original.

Comment: You could input the number as a string, use `std::reverse` and compare.  No need to convert to number and then back to string.

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool is_palindrom(int num)
{
     int dig,rev=0,n=num;
     while (num != 0)
     {
         dig = num % 10;
         rev = (rev * 10) + dig;
         num = num / 10;
     }

     return (n == rev);
}
int main()
{
     vector<int> v={300003, 310013, 320023, 330033, 340043, 350053,123};
     for(auto n:v)
     {
         cout<<n<<" is "<<(is_palindrom(n)?"":"not ")<<"palindrom."<<endl;
     }
}
```

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: Also, you're lacking a definition of `vector` - assuming that's intended to be `std::vector`, then you need to include `<vector>`.